# Open 2 Urls google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I found this code which allows me to open a url.
But I would like it to open a second tab for example:
    https://www.google.com/search?q=
and
    https://www.bing.com/search?q=

I'm a beginner and can't find a solution thank you for help.

```
function openurl() {
   var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
   var selection2 = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
   var html = "<script>window.open('" + selection2 + selection + "');google.script.host.close(); 
</script>";  
   var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);            
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Tab');
}
```

Comment: you can create an html popup response and add html into it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it exceeds my skills